# illegal access mode 0 while deleting file in ruby

Tags: jruby, delete-file

I am getting following error while deleting a file:

> illegal access mode 0

and I am just using ruby `File.delete`.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Which version of ruby?  C-ruby or JRUby?  Can you post your entire script?  Which OS are you on?  Is the file local or on a file share?  What are its permissions?

Comment: Thanks rob for giving a hint how should be my question. I should be more specify. I solved this issue. I am opening the excel file with gem spreadsheet and at the end i gave File.delete(file_path). File is not closed you its prevented me from deleting. I closed the file and called delete method, its work fine.

Comment: I suggest posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved cheaply. 
I have used spreadsheet gem and i open a file using that. At the end when i tried to delete that file i got this error. 
This is very cheap move, just i need to close that file. file was lock mode so it restricted to delete.